# Referencing a cell into a formula

Tags: google-sheets

This question pertains to Google Sheets. In column F of one "List" tab of my sheet, I have the name of all the other tabs in my sheet. All the other tabs contain information specific to one single topic. Im trying to get all of column N in "List" to pull up cell G2 of each sheet. So far, ive been using this:

='(sheet name)'!G2    ;in the N column, changing (sheet name) manually and individually

But I'd rather have the content of the F fill the (sheet name) part of the formula. Any way to do so?

Comment: [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sheet names in column **F**, in **N1** enter:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & F1 & "'!G2")
```

and copy down.  *Please note the single quotes in the formula.*

[image]

This should work for both Excel and Google Sheets.